# Spring Boot Maven Project configuration with MS SQL Database integratedSecurity=true

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot, maven

Is it possible to pack the required DLL dependencies to use MSSQL integratedSecurity option without having to put DLL files in the target machines JVMs folders or to automate this process with Maven?

My pom.xml JDBC dependencies:

```
<properties>
    ...
    <spring-boot.version>2.4.4</spring-boot.version>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <version.java>11</version.java>
    ...
</properties>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.1.jre11</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc_auth</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.1.x64</version>
    <type>dll</type>
</dependency>
```

My application.yml configuration:

```
spring.datasource:
  url: jdbc:sqlserver://SOMESERVER;databaseName=SOMEDATABASE;integratedSecurity=true
  driverClassName: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

My error:

```
2021-04-01 11:20:17,133 ERROR [main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool: HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This driver is not configured for integrated authentication. ClientConnectionId:2a5498f2-4672-42b4-87a6-4cb2087ee382
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:3206)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<init>(AuthenticationJNI.java:72)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:4015)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:4004)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7418)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3272)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2768)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2418)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2265)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1291)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:881)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:121)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:358)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:206)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:477)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:560)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:115)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.fetchConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:158)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:116)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:223)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.getMetaData(Unknown Source)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.initDatabaseType(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:1556)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.initDataSource(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:1511)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.init(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:1001)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.cfg.ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.buildProcessEngine(ProcessEngineConfigurationImpl.java:972)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.SpringTransactionsProcessEngineConfiguration.buildProcessEngine(SpringTransactionsProcessEngineConfiguration.java:67)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:55)
    at org.camunda.bpm.engine.spring.ProcessEngineFactoryBean.getObject(ProcessEngineFactoryBean.java:34)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:169)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:101)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1884)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1266)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:345)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:657)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:601)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:887)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:791)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1354)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1313)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302)
    at com.morneaushepell.camunda.BootApp.main(BootApp.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no mssql-jdbc_auth-9.2.1.x64 in java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin, C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin, C:\Windows\system32, C:\Windows, C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath, C:\Windows\system32, C:\Windows, C:\Windows\System32\Wbem, C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\, C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\, C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0\, C:\Program Files\Git\cmd, .]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:2660)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:827)
    at java.base/java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1871)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI.<clinit>(AuthenticationJNI.java:51)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:4014)
    ... 71 common frames omitted
```

Is it possible to pack the required DLL into the project using Maven and a Spring Boot project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you can obtain the required result by combining several Maven plugins.

On one hand, you can use the [copy dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html) mojo to copy the dynamic library to a certain location. Consider for instance:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>copy-dependencies</id>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/dll</outputDirectory>
                <includeArtifactIds>mssql-jdbc_auth</includeArtifactIds>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Now, the library should be available so it can be loaded by `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.AuthenticationJNI` and `System.loadLibrary`.

Java will look for native libraries in the system library path.

As you can see in the stack trace, the system library path is defined by the system property `java.library.path` - typically it is well suited if you have only a JNI library - and different environment properties, dependent on the operating system, `PATH` in Windows and `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in Linux and Unix systems - relevant if you have dependent libraries, for example.

The way in which that properties an environment variables can be defined depends on how you are running your application.

One first, less portable, approach will be to use the above-mentioned `copy-dependencies` mojo to output the dependencies to a common, standard, directory usually included in the `PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables.

If you are using the Spring Boot Maven plugin, probably you have [several ways](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#run) to do this.

**[jvmArguments](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-run-parameters-details-jvmArguments)**

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <jvmArguments>
      -Djava.library.path=${project.build.directory}/dll
    </jvmArguments>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**[systemPropertyVariables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-run-parameters-details-systemPropertyVariables)**

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <systemPropertyVariables>
      <java.library.path>${project.build.directory}/dll</java.library.path>
    </systemPropertyVariables>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

**[environmentVariables](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-run-parameters-details-environmentVariables)**

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <environmentVariables>
      <PATH>${project.build.directory}/dll</PATH>
    </environmentVariables>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

All these features require a forked process.

Similar features exists for the [Maven exec plugin](https://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html) as well.

As you indicated in your comment, the suggested approaches are more focused probably on a development, not final deployment perspective.

The way in which the problem can be solved from a final deployment perspective will depend on the actual mechanism that you are using to run the application.

If you were running the application on Linux, or at least you have a suitable native library to perform the integrated security authentication, I would recommend you to pack the application in a docker container and perform the necessary tweaks in the JVM configuration to make it work.

Unfortunately, there is no native library version of `mssql-jdbc_auth` for Linux and, although you have the ability to [configure Kerberos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-kerberos-integrated-authentication-to-connect-to-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) for a similar purpose, you will run into a problem probably greater than the one you are trying to solve.

You can try packing the dependency as a resource in your jar/war archive, copy it to a writable location - the folder identified by `java.io.tempdir` usually will fit these requirements - on application startup, and then load then using `System.load` - not `System.loadLibrary` - passing as argument the full path and name including extension of the copied dll: honestly I never tested it before, but as far as a native library is loaded only once in the JVM and second load tries will have no effect perhaps it will allow you to preload the library before the MS SQL Server driver itself.

Probably this approach will only be suitable if you run your app as a standalone Spring Boot application: if you run your application in a `traditional` container, Tomcat, etcetera, as a WAR file, the fact that a shared library can only be loaded once maybe can cause you problems when redeploying the application.

For `traditional` container deployments, in my opinion, the best option is use the shared library directory they usually provide and place there your dll prior application deployment.

Comment: All of this must be done on build phase, right? I am unable to pack this all as a WAR/JAR and then make it happen in the user/server machine, right?

Comment: @BBacon Thank you very much for the feedback. I updated the answer. Please, can you review it?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to run this setup without install any DDL and just using java 8 and dockerized sql server 2019. Currently im using a previous version of the drive:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>8.4.1.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You did not use the DLL Maven dependency too? With integratedSecurity=true and NO login and password in the JDBC path?

Comment: I just reduced to Java 8 and removed the DLL dependency... and it does not work.

Comment: Are you using this dependency? try it.

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
   <artifactId>mssql-jdbc_auth</artifactId>
   <version>8.4.1.x64</version>
   <type>dll</type>
</dependency>

Comment: Yes I am, just as in my original post... I have the mssql-jdbc_auth dependency as dll, and I tried downgrading to your version. But it is still not detected and used in my Java Path by the Spring Boot aplication. Everything is done as described in my post.

Comment: idk what happen,maybe you have more then 1 jdk installed or using different maven version to build?

Comment: I tried using spring boot maven plugin and maven war plugin to pack the war/jar. Same problems occurs. Only one JDK installed (JDK 11, then I uninstalled it and installed JDK8 to reproduce your environment. The DLL still does not get loaded. As far as I now... I can't load DLLs from inside JAR/WAR, so I don't know how any of this should work.